# Comparing 2 excel documents

Tags: excel, vba

I have two really huge excel documents.

Below is just a sample of data in it.

Document 1 contains:

```
base_id
bd9ce21c-bc57-4e21-adf9a9693cbc
5b0a3d79-ff6a-41fd-a28aa6a92164
b7d80042-1fcf-4661-21d7dd5b1fbd
B211B098-0544-4CDF-A2F93EAD22A4
4FB55FE5-AE6A-425F-8B31E345181A
```

Document 2 contains:

```
path_id                   gate_no count text_id
54ecfc619d1333b86a3a9cd9    3816    0   {"abcd":"50C53378-5833-4827-9C2F-3211D3F42F13"  abcd_tub:"831e590de0cc185248f4208fc5d5ee89d2d"  abcd_cub:"1537fe51004bae1e71480b154372"}
54ecfc619d1333b86a3a9cd9    3005    0   {"bolt":"66db1807f1e4a072744a77fd8429b5"    mega:"a1cd73b41d6b3eae97dbbdd76e323a44ab5140"}  
54ecfc619d1333b86a3a9cd9    2595    0   {"bolt":"c58634ccdcb5e81eb0b447679b756" mega:"32b74bf7024944b457c69c000e44d43"} 
54ecfc619d1333b86a3a9cd9    2220    0   {"bolt":"acf98549461b87bcfe2c5190d6c"   mega:"2c1c788440d85ea70597ce135ccf2316748f"}    
54ecfc619d1333b86a3a9cd9    2160    0   {"abcd":"16F8E7-F395-4551-B8C7-5FC8B"   abcd_tub:"a5301e4dfc6bad809a2917f495fc6f7"  abcd_cub:"4e5da03ffb35a0f17726acb60c8dc"}
```

What i need to do is:

Check if the base_id from document 1 exists in any of the rows of document 2.

If exists, get the list of base_id and the row

If it does not exist, get the list of base_ids only.

What is a best way to do the above comparison in EXCEL?
If not excel, are there any sample script samples that i can look at?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: not sure about reading excel format, but if you can save them as csv, you could check this easily using bash.

Comment: Assume you already have a way to read excel files: Why not parse the document 2 and store the necessary data in a dictionary, i.e., `var dict = {}`, which is easier to look up when matching the base_id in 1st document? The downside of this approach is high memory overhead but I think it's unavoidable.... (unless your files are indexed/sorted)

Comment: @ArnonZilca Yes I have it in csv format. Can you recommend a script samle/ link which does something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Assumed your files look exactly like they are in the question (they can have commas instead of tabs - but they need to be textual, not in Excel format).

It's not that efficient but if the files are not really long it shouldn't matter.
Hope I understood what you're trying to achieve correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

file1="file1"
file2="file2"

for id in $(tail -n+2 "${file1}"); do
    if ! grep "${id}" "${file2}"; then
        echo "${id}"
    fi
done
```

Btw, in your example none of the `base_id`s exist in file2.